# Hiding empty categories in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

How can I hide empty categories when I query to display them? Empty categories are those that no products are assigned to them..
Here is my controller

```
    public function showSubCats($categoryId) {

         $subcats = SubCategories::where('category_id', '=', $categoryId)->get();
         return View::make('site.subcategory', [            
             'subcats' => $subcats
         ]); 
}
```

Here is the view

```
@if(count($subcats) > 0)
     <div class="row">
         @foreach($subcats as $i => $subcategory)   

              // display categories

         @endforeach             
@else
         There is no products assigned to this category                  
     </div>

@endif
```

This is my SubCategories model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Product', 'category_id');
} 
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('SubCategories', 'category_id');
}   
public function lowestProduct() {
    return $this->products()->selectRaw('*, max(price) as aggregate')
    ->groupBy('products.product_id')->orderBy('aggregate');
}
```

In product table I have column which is `sub_cat_id` and holds category in which is assigned. If is 0 is not assigned to any category.

How can I hide empty categories now?

Comment: You should use the whereHas() method -https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `where` in addition to your model

`return $this->hasMany('Action')->where('sub_cat_id', 1);`

**Note :**

I believe that you neeed to take the records only that has `sub_cat_id` as 1. If not change it to 0 or accordingly.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Not only `sub_cat_id=1` ... 1 is dynamical and saves the sub_cat_id.. if is 0 just hide it. If is !=0 show..

Comment: Where should I put this `return $this->hasMany('Action')->where('sub_cat_id', 1);`

Comment: To your `products()` . Yeah you can do like that too

Comment: Like this too `return $this->hasMany('Action')->where('sub_cat_id', =, 1);` .. if you need you can add more conditions in your model

Comment: Tried like this in `produc()` - `return $this->hasMany('Product', 'sub_cat_id')->where('sub_cat_id', '!=', 0);`

Comment: If you consider from your controller then, `$subcats = SubCategories::where('category_id', '=', $categoryId)->where('sub_cat_id', '=', 0)->get();` ?

Comment: Hm.. something isn't right here. Right now I have 2 products assigned to same sub-category and one empty sub-category. I see sub-category which has products but still also see the one that doesn't have products. But second sub-category doesn't persist in `product.sub_cat_id` since isn't added product to it..

Comment: So, the point is if you have any Sub category, then in the Category table you will hve sub_cat_id will be 0 .. Isn't it ?

Comment: No, I have `category_id` column in `sub-category` table. This way I save sub-category to main category. In `products` table I have `category_id` and `sub_cat_id` columns.. Now when I click on main category I want to see only sub-categories which has at least 1 product assigned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118224/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-jordan-vit).